# WiFi switch not working on HP pavilion dv4 using ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, wireless, hp

I have installed ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop alongside windows 8.

the wifi switch doesn't work. pressing it doesn't do anything at all.

any help regarding this?

this is what I get from

```
rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

and this I get by

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 98:4b:e1:ea:ba:03
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5390 [802.11 b/g/n 1T1R G-band PCI Express Single Chip]
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 90:00:4e:82:25:3f
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.8.0-30-generic firmware=0.34 ip=10.9.4.55 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:c2500000-c250ffff
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What is the output of the commands `rfkill list all` and `sudo lshw -C network`? These commands are typed in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T). You can [edit] your question and paste the output there by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath the text of your question. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the logs as suggested by @Alaa